# Measurable Space VS Measure Space

Tags: measure-theory

From what I understood

a Measurable Space is $(X,S)$ where $X$ is a set and $S\subset P(X)$ is a $\sigma$ algebra

a Measure Space is $(X,S,\mu)$ where $X$ is a set and $S\subset P(X)$ is a $\sigma$ algebra and $\mu$ is a measure.

Is it the same like a metric space? we can a general space and then add a metric so it becomes a metric space?

Does all Measurable Space can be a Measure Space? (as the name suggests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can always define a measure on any sigma algebra. Take any point $x \in X$ and define $\mu (E)=1$ if $x \in E$ and $0$ otherwise. So any measurable space can  be made into a measure space.